# How to set applications to open in specific workspaces in Loki?

Tags: workspace

For example, Firefox should always open up in workspace 8, Emacs in 2 and so on. All methods online which use ccsm, gnome tweak, etc are geared to gnome or unity. Devilspie was suggested somewhere, but couldn't get it to work in this case. Is there any way to implement this in Loki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone out there needs this, devilspie2 does the job.

```
if (get_application_name()=="Firefox") then
    set_window_workspace(8);
end
```

Save the above snippet as `~/.config/devilspie2/Firefox.lua`